# HttpWebResponse GetResponse timeout

Tags: c#, winforms, rest, httpwebrequest

My question is quite similar to this topic however I've tried different versions of .Net Framework and still doesn't work:
[Machine-Specific HttpWebResponse Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221352/machine-specific-httpwebresponse-timeout)

In my program, I have a login function to send `POST` command to a server.  Every time I start up my program, the `POST` command ALWAYS timeout. Once the timeout message pops out, hit login again and the POST command can successfully send to the server side. But in my 2 different VM (with OS: Win7Pro CHT/ Win7Pro CHS) it has no problem.

My dev environment: Windows 7 Pro CHS, .Net Framework 4.7.2

I've tried:

- set `myRequest.Timeout`
- use `System.Net.Http` and `HttpClient`
- set `myRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false`
- set `myRequest.Abort()` and `myResponse.Close()`
- install `.Net Framework 4.5.2`, `4.7.2` and `4.8.0`

Sadly non of above work.

Here's my POST function:

```
public string SendPostCommand(string url, string data)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetBytes(data);
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        myRequest.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.Timeout = 500;
        myRequest.Headers.Add("userKey", "--------------------");
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        // Get response
        using (HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse())
        // --------------------------------- ALWAYS HANG HERE
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
            {
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                myRequest.Abort();
                myResponse.Close();
                reader.Close();
                return content;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here's the way I call the function:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dataDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dataDict.Add("UserName", txtUsername.Text);
    dataDict.Add("UserPassword", txtPwd.Text);

    string url = frmMain.g_authAddress + "SysUser/Login";
    try
    {
        string response = SendPostCommand(url, ConvertDictToString(dataDict));

        HttpResponse responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpResponse>(response);
        switch (responseObj.code)
        {
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("Login success.");
                frmMain.g_CurrentUser = txtUsername.Text;
                frmMain.g_isProgramReady = true;
                this.Close();
                break;
            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show("User non-exist.");
                break;
            case 2:
                MessageBox.Show("Machine non-exist.");
                break;
            case 3:
                MessageBox.Show("User has no access.");
                break;
            case 4:
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect password");
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show(responseObj.ErMsg);
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
}
```

Also I tried a using `httpclient` but still failed. Not sure if this is the way that commentor mentioned about `turn SendPostCommand() into an async method and await the result`

```
private string testPost(string url, string content)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("userKey", "--------------------");
    HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("SysUser/Login", contentPost).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the async versions of WebRequest / WebResponse methods, turn `SendPostCommand()` into an async method and await the result, setting a more *sensible* Timeout? Why hard-code `500 ms`?

Comment: And why use HttpWebRequest? That's a legacy class. In fact, in .NET Core it's just a compatibility wrapper over HttpClient

Comment: In any case, 500ms is an impossible timeout. Unlike HttpClient which caches connections, HttpWebRequest has to resolve URL through DNS every time. That can take up to 15 seconds. The DNS server may be busy, the connection slow, there may be 10 router/proxy hops between the client and DNS server. The URL may not be cached in the DNS server, so it has to ask other servers. With HttpClient though, the socket connection is cached and reused so after the first call there's no need to resolve the address again

Comment: Then there's the latency between client and server. A request may have to go through a dozen hops to reach the server, through the local router, the ISP's routers and proxies, perhaps up to a backbone or even another country if the server uses a different ISP. What is the latency if you `ping` the target server? If you use `tracert` how many hops are there?

Comment: the reason I set 500ms is that the client and server are in same local network hook up to the same switch (192.168.10.*) for test

Comment: Typically if the request is hanging it is because the server is expecting more data from the client because the client hasn't properly signaled no more data is coming. So for your code, `newStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);` you could try making sure your post data ends with two newlines, e.g. `\n\n`. Or you might have to supply a `boundary` in the header, and then terminate the post data with the `boundary` string. The boundary string is just a made-up string that can be anything you choose, e.g. `------\n\n`.